# Optimal way to compute neighbors for a sudoku cell in a fixed size matrix representation

Tags: c, sudoku

For a university assignment I'm implementing a sudoku solver. Part of the implementation is method neighbors, which given a cell (x) computes it's neighbors. That is, the cells which domain is dependent on value of x.

Naturally, for a game of sudoku list of cell (x) neighbors is a union of all cells in same column as x, same row as x and same 3x3 partition as x. While first two subsets can be easily computed with a loop, I cant come up with a neat way to collect partition neighbors since depending on where in the partition the cell is located there are 9 distinct non-overlapping scenarios.

Perhaps it may be a better solution to store values in a set or dynamic list and dedup it after, but I'm working with C programming language and want to keep usage of libraries to libc. I also don't need said data structures anywhere else so I'm hesitant to implement them.

Below is my implementation.

```c
/*
 * neighbours
 * Auxiliary function to populate array with neighbour indices for cell (x) specified by index (idx).
 * That is, populate the array with indices of the cells such that constraints on their domain depend on value of x.
 * This function is only declared to increase level of abstraction and simplify coding.
 * It also doesn't generalize for different board sizes as it assumes all cells have 20 neighbours.
 * It is not intended to be used outside the scope of ac3, and therefore is marked auxiliary.
 *
 * @param idx   index of the cell which neighbours are to be determined
 * @param buf   a pointer to integer array with at least 20 elements (20 are populated)
 * @return      1 if successful, 0 otherwise
 */
int neighbours(int idx, int* buf);

int
neighbours(int idx, int* buf) {
    int x, y, partition_x, partition_y, cursor;

    cursor = 4;

    x = idx % BOARD_WIDTH;
    y = idx / BOARD_WIDTH;

    partition_x = x % 3;
    partition_y = y % 3;


    if (partition_x == 0 && partition_y == 0) {
        buf[0] = IDX(x+1, y+1);
        buf[1] = IDX(x+2, y+2);
        buf[2] = IDX(x+2, y+1);
        buf[3] = IDX(x+1, y+2);
    }

    if (partition_x == 0 && partition_y == 1) {
        buf[0] = IDX(x+1, y-1);
        buf[1] = IDX(x+2, y+2);
        buf[2] = IDX(x+2, y-1);
        buf[3] = IDX(x+1, y+2);
    }

    if (partition_x == 0 && partition_y == 2) {
        buf[0] = IDX(x+1, y-1);
        buf[1] = IDX(x+2, y-2);
        buf[2] = IDX(x+2, y-1);
        buf[3] = IDX(x+1, y-2);
    }

    if (partition_x == 1 && partition_y == 0) {
        buf[0] = IDX(x-1, y+1);
        buf[1] = IDX(x+1, y+2);
        buf[2] = IDX(x+1, y+1);
        buf[3] = IDX(x-1, y+2);
    }

    if (partition_x == 1 && partition_y == 1) {
        buf[0] = IDX(x-1, y-1);
        buf[1] = IDX(x+1, y+2);
        buf[2] = IDX(x+1, y-1);
        buf[3] = IDX(x-1, y+2);
    }

    if (partition_x == 1 && partition_y == 2) {
        buf[0] = IDX(x-1, y-1);
        buf[1] = IDX(x+1, y-2);
        buf[2] = IDX(x+1, y-1);
        buf[3] = IDX(x-1, y-2);
    }

    if (partition_x == 2 && partition_y == 0) {
        buf[0] = IDX(x-1, y+1);
        buf[1] = IDX(x-2, y+2);
        buf[2] = IDX(x-2, y+1);
        buf[3] = IDX(x-1, y+2);
    }

    if (partition_x == 2 && partition_y == 1) {
        buf[0] = IDX(x-1, y-1);
        buf[1] = IDX(x-2, y+2);
        buf[2] = IDX(x-2, y-1);
        buf[3] = IDX(x-1, y+2);
    }

    if (partition_x == 2 && partition_y == 2) {
        buf[0] = IDX(x-1, y-1);
        buf[1] = IDX(x-2, y-2);
        buf[2] = IDX(x-2, y-1);
        buf[3] = IDX(x-1, y-2);
    }


    for (int nx = 0; nx < BOARD_WIDTH; nx++) {
        if (nx == x)
            continue;
        buf[cursor] = IDX(nx, y);
        cursor++;
    }

    for (int ny = 0; ny < BOARD_WIDTH; ny++) {
        if (ny == y)
            continue;
        buf[cursor] = IDX(x, ny);
        cursor++;
    }



    return 1;
}
```

I'm struggling with implementing the method cleanly,

Answer (score 2):

The block which contains cell (y, x) is at

```
int basecol = (x / 3) * 3;
int baserow = (y / 3) * 3;
```

and you can then do a simple pair of nested loops

```
for(int j = baserow; j < baserow + 3; j++) {
    for(int i = basecol; i<basecol + 3; i++) {
        if(j == y && i == x)
            printf(" self  ");
        else
            printf("(%d, %d) ", j, i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: This will duplicate the values from column and row of cell x. This is precisely the reason as to why I'm struggling to find a more general implementation.

Comment: I thought your problem was computing which block easily. You can make a lookup table first, of the 20 cells affected by each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in Java to create a look-up table of the 81 sectors of each of the 81 cells of a grid. A sector includes 1+20 cells located either in the same row, or in the same column, or in the same block of a cell (the 1 above).

```
int[][] sector_table = createSectorTable();

int[][] createSectorTable() {
    int[][] st = new int[81][20];
    for (int sec = 0; sec < 81; sec++) {
        int celrow = sec / 9, celcol = sec % 9;
        int blo = Blo(sec), colb = 3 * (blo % 3), rowb = 3 * (blo / 3);
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i / 3 != celcol / 3) {
                st[sec][j] = i + 9 * celrow;
                j++;
            }
            if (i / 3 != celrow / 3) {
                st[sec][j] = celcol + 9 * i;
                j++;
            }
            if ((colb + i % 3) / 3 == celcol / 3 && (rowb + i / 3) / 3 == celrow / 3) {
                if (sec != colb + i % 3 + 9 * (rowb + i / 3)) {
                    st[sec][j] = colb + i % 3 + 9 * (rowb + i / 3);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sector: " + sec + " " + Arrays.toString(st[sec]) + "  array.length:" + st[sec].length);
    }
    return st;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why it's organized in this way? I thought that at worst, a lookup table would need 81x20 elements, where for each cell index it's neighbour indices would be stored. This seem to operate by creating a bitmap of the whole field for each cell, masking it's non neighbours. Why is it done like this?